# Unable to create Leads and Contacts from Outlook 2010 Side Panel

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

Cannot find CREATE Leads and Contacts button in Outlook 2010 Side Panel - Salesforce to Outlook.

Did I missed any configuration step or is it not available in Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, We cannot create Leads & Contacts in SFO 2010, we can only sync them from Salesforce.
We can only create Opportunity, Task and Cases from Outlook.

Comment: It was not working in earlier version 2.9... But in Recent Update(ver 3.1) it is enabled/working.